# want to create state combo box block in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-blocks

I want to list states in a combo box to be displayed in block in left side bar.
Depending on the selecting of state I want to filter the HTML code within page nodes.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are unfamilliar with how Drupal modules are created, work through [Creating modules - a tutorial: Drupal 6.x](http://drupal.org/node/206753)
2. Create a form. The [Forms API QuickStart Guide](http://api.drupal.org/api/file/developer/topics/forms_api.html/6) and the [Forms API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6) tell you how this is done in Drupal.
3. Put the form into a block by implementing [`hook_block`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6).

How to proceed from there depends largely on what type of filtering you need. In any case [`hook_nodeapi`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) is invoked on various node-related occasions, so you might want to implement it to do the actual filtering.